# Does Watin support xPath?

Tags: watin

Does Watin support xPath?

How can I access an element that does not have any id or class or something unique to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it does not.

My suggestion would be to look for an element container that has an id / class / name to identify it and then look up this element inside it.

If you are running into problems with identifying such elements, you might want to post some of the DOM that you.